# POSTing protos to GAE Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, protocol-buffers

Python/Development newbie here.

My computer is collecting data, which it then stores in google protocol buffers (protos). I want to POST these protos to my google app engine account's data store, so that the data can then be accessed by my app when necessary.

I was trying to use httplib2 to POST the data, but just plugging the URL in doesn't work. Does some kind of special handler need to be created in the app to receive the proto and store it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have your app.yml directing the request to the appropriate handler.  There are examples of how to do this in the [Getting Started With App Engine in Python 2.7 Guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld).  I'll assume that you've already done this and (from the same document) added your handler's route and python class to the webapp2.WSGIApplication constructor.

To store the packed protocol buffers in your app engine application, you should be able to:

```
data = dict(form_protobuf_field = packed_proto_buff_string)
resp, content = h.request("http://[app-name].appspot.com/route", "POST", urlencode(data))
```

...or did you want to unpack the proto buff and post it by addressing each of its constituents to a different field in the form?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give that a shot. I found the getting started guide difficult to follow as several of the examples didn't work, so I really appreciate the help. The big (read dumb) question I have left is, what's the route? The thing is that I don't want to protos to be publicly accessible, so I don't want to just post them up (packed) to an html page. This is purely backend data.